# Connection timed out in Mobaxterm

Tags: window

I'm getting this issue...what will be the solution for this?
Network error: Connection timed out.

to run normally. I have tried with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGbeJ7PrlFM but found ans.
I'm getting these issues. Network error: Connection timed out.
Network error: Connection timed out.

Network error: Connection timed out.

Network error: Connection timed out.

Network error: Connection timed out.

Network error: Connection timed out.
─

Session stopped
- Press  to exit tab
- Press R to restart session
- Press S to save terminal output to file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.